# R auto.arima does not detect intercept

Tags: r, time-series, arima, forecast

I have a time series with monthly data. I am trying to adjust a model to it and as a first approach, I'm trying to fit an ARIMA or SARIMA model. This is my series

[image: time series]

I am using the `auto.arima` function from the `forecast` package like this

```
data.ts <- ts(data,start=c(2015,10),freq=12)
auto.arima(data.ts)
```

but the result does not return an intercept parameter as expected. Here is the outcome

```
Series: data.ts
ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,1)[12] 

Coefficients:
            ma1       sma1
      -0.338450  -0.596802
s.e.   0.130621   0.183938

sigma^2 = 1315.65:  log likelihood = -337.35
AIC=680.69   AICc=681.08   BIC=687.31
```

Maybe I'm getting this wrong (I'm new to time series modeling) but I thought the intercept given by the `auto.arima` function stands for the mean of the process, that it is *clearly* different from zero in my case.

Note: I cannot post the actual data but I don't think that is necessary to answer my question.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: I can't really post my data since it is not in my power to make it public.

Comment: I think having some kind of example dataset would be helpful here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `arima()`:

`data.ts <- ts(data,start=c(2015,10),freq=12)`

`arima(data.ts)`:

```
     `Call:
      arima(x = test)
      Coefficients:
           intercept
            6.8750
     s.e.   2.4395
     sigma^2 estimated as 47.61:  log likelihood = -26.8,  aic = 57.61
```

Comment: But I am not trying (yet) to forecast new values, just trying to fit a model to my data. Does that affect the intercept of the model? That's my main issue here.

Comment: Like, you would like to put specific components (p, d, q) of ARIMA?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to estimate the ARIMA parameters of my time series but the `auto.arima` function is not getting the means of the series as the intercept and I don't know why.

Comment: Try using arima(data.ts)

Comment: You should get something like Coefficients:
      intercept and below its value. if the problem are just the components you can try Arima(data.ts,order=(p,d,q))

Comment: I tried that since it is a way of getting the mean (plus its standard error) of the series. But why isn't `auto.arima` detecting it?  (I get 286.5 and s.e. 6.6)

Comment: It seems to show it only for ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean, in other cases it shows ma1,ma2 and drift parameters

Comment: So would it be acceptable to subtract the means to the series and then apply `auto.arima`? Or would those parameters be somehow 'constructed' or manipulated?

Comment: I don't think it would solve your problem though